# Solutions with disjoint support to the continuity equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Suppose $f,g. u \in C^{1}((0,T) \times \mathbb{R})$ with$$ \partial_{t}(f+g) + \partial_{x}((f+g)u) = 0, \quad \text{on } (0,T) \times \mathbb{R}$$ where for each $t \in (0,T)$ we have $\text{spt}(f(t,\cdot)) \cap \text{spt}(g(t,\cdot)) = \emptyset$. Then do we have $$\partial_{t}f + \partial_{x}(fu) = \partial_{t}g + \partial_{x}(gu)= 0 \quad \text{on } (0,T) \times \mathbb{R}?$$

I think it should be true almost trivially but I don't know if I am making a mistake. Since $f+g$ is either equal to $f$ or equal to $g$ (Depending on which support you are in) then this should lead to the desired conclusion. Or is there some sort of pathological example I am missing?

Comment: ‘spt’ means the support?

Comment: @Aruralreader yes

Comment: With the regularity of the functions you have, the argument is fine. Once the partial $t$ is not a continuous function anymore (entering the realm of distributions), the supports of $\partial_t f(t, \cdot)$ and $\partial_t g(t, \cdot)$may overlap at an arbitrary small interval while the original functions' support does not overlap. Such examples can be constructed using characteristic functions.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao but how is that so? If you have a distribution $f$ then $(f', \phi) = - (f, \phi')$ and since $supp(\phi') \subseteq supp(\phi)$ surely we must have $(f', \phi) = 0$ whenever $supp(\phi) \cap supp(f) = \emptyset$? i.e. isn't it true that $supp(\partial_{t}f) \subseteq supp(f)$ even if $f$ is a distribution?

Comment: Let us say $t\in \mathbb{R}$, imaging $f$ is $0$ when $t\leq 0$ and $1$ when $t>0$; $g$ is $1$ when $t\leq 0$ and $0$ from $t>0$, then both the derivatives have support at 0, if one is willing to extend the definition of support for regular functions to distributions.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao But in your example $supp(f) =[0, \infty)$ while $supp(g) =[-\infty, 0]$. They are not disjoint?

Comment: If you consider closure then yes. What I meant was if the support you define is $\operatorname {supp} (f)=\{x\in \operatorname{dom}(f)\,:\,f(x)\neq 0\}$ then differentiability will play a role.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao oh ok i have always seen support defined as the closure of that set, in what context do people define it in the way you suggested?

Comment: In the context of the problems I usually work on, support is typically compact (thus closed). I think I saw your question yesterday and went on Wikipedia to check the formal definition of support, then I saw the first definition there, and that counterexample popped up.